# Render a YouTube video with iframes in Angular

Tags: javascript, iframe, strip-tags

I have YouTube videos that I want to embed on my angular website. The links are wrapped in iframes

**example**

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/tpbw5O-_mFQ" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

I am fetching the link from a Mysql database but when try to render the video it just displays the iframe tags, instead of the video. How do I strip the tags and display the video.

Comment: FYI, it is pure HTML, not linked to Angular

Comment: Please show the relevant Angular piece of code